# Whats the python script to check if an cardano address has a script flag?

Tags: blockfrost, address, script, python

I have a script to fetch asset name, address from a policy id with blockfrost API, now I need to see if the asset is in a smart contract script. I have no coding skills but followed a tutorial to get this far. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[PyCardano](https://github.com/Python-Cardano/pycardano) can help you to find the address type.

For example, [addr1wyzynye0nksztrfzpsulsq7whr3vgh7uvp0gm4p0x42ckkqqq6kxq](https://cardanoscan.io/address/addr1wyzynye0nksztrfzpsulsq7whr3vgh7uvp0gm4p0x42ckkqqq6kxq) is the script address of [Spacebudz](https://spacebudz.io/FAQ/). You can decode it into an `Address` object using pycardano, and the `address_type` field will tell you the information about this address.

```
>>> from pycardano import Address
>>> addr = Address.from_primitive("addr1wyzynye0nksztrfzpsulsq7whr3vgh7uvp0gm4p0x42ckkqqq6kxq")
>>> addr.address_type
<AddressType.SCRIPT_NONE: 7>
```

The output `SCRIPT_NONE` tells us that this address's payment part is a script (first half is `SCRIPT`), and the address doesn't have staking part (second half is `NONE`). All possible address types could be found in this [doc](https://pycardano.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pycardano.address.html#pycardano.address.AddressType).